# Install python 3.9 in linux server which is already having 2.7 without any side effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

My companies production linux server has python 2.7. Also, none of my colleagues know if anything is using python 2.7 on that machine. I want to use latest django on it so I want to install python 3.9 on that server. If I do "yum install python" will it cause any negative impact on my machine?

Comment: This question is so vague that it cannot be reliably answered. What is the distribution for starters? I understand that it is some version of RHEL/CentOS but which version?

Comment: If you and your colleagues are not sure, how can this be decided here, with so few information? Maybe better try this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if I use virtualenv and try installing python 3.9 with yum on it?

Comment: Creating a virtual env requires the interpreter to be installed already. Replacing it later is most likely just going to breaking the env.

Answer (score 0):

I think, here your solution:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/

and

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/14/python-in-rhel-8/